# Fancybox + Firefox on Mac

Tags: jquery, firefox, pdf, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm wanting to use Fancybox to load PDFs and I have gone through multiple forums to find the answer and have tried many suggestions, but I just can't seem to get it to work in Firefox on my Mac. I have used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".pdf").click(function() {
$.fancybox({
'width': 700, // or whatever
'height': 900,
'autoSize': false,
'content': '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />', 
});
return false;
}); // pdf 
); // ready
```

In conjunction with this link:

```
    <a class="pdf" href="sample.pdf"><img src="test.jpg" width="81" height="108" alt="testimg" /></a>
```

My test page with screen shot can be seen here:

http://shannawise.com/clients/fancy_box_test.html

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

SideNote: I got the googledoc suggestion to work, but do not like the way it renders the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using fancybox v2.1.4 ... save yourself some headaches and use the `iframe` mode as in the following code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".pdf").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        }
    });
});
```

If you prefer to set fixed dimensions for the box, include the options

```
width: 700, // as JFK always says : or whatever
height: 900,
fitToView : false
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EUt9A/)**

BTW, the code you were using works for fancybox v1.3.4 but not for v2.x

Comment: I'm so glad you responded! It works! I thought I had the latest version since I downloaded it from the GitHub link but i guess not. Thanks again for all your help :)